# Function of Exact distance to Another Function

Tags: maple

I want to find a function $h(x)$ that always has exactly 1 distance to $f(x)$. This is called a parallel curve as I understand it, however, I don't want to do it this way, and I believe I solved the problem, however, my CAS software (Maple) cannot compute the function I get. I have done the following:

I have two values, $a$ and $b$, which represent a point $(a,b)$. I want to find the $b$-coordinate for any $a$-coordinate, i.e. a function $b(a)$.
I start by assuming an $a$-value:
$$a=1.5$$
I now define my function I want to stay at $1$ distance to
$$f(x)=-x^2+2$$
I then define a function that can give me the distance between the point $(a, b)$ and the point $(x, f(x)$
$$g(x)=\sqrt{(a-x)^2+(b-f(x))^2}$$
I want to find an a-value for the point where the minimum of $g(x)$ is exactly 1, i.e. an $a$ for which $g(x)=1$ and $g'(x)=0$:
$$g'(x)=0 \Leftrightarrow b=\frac{0.25(4x^3-6x-3)}{x}$$

I now plug this into $g(x)$ and set it to $1$:
$$\sqrt{(1.5-x)^2+(- \frac{0.25(4x^3-6x-3}{x}-f(x))^2}=1 \Leftrightarrow x=0.69$$

I then plug this x-value into $g(x)$ and solve for $b$, giving me $b=2.11$

Now this is fine, but as mentioner earlier, I would like to find a function $b(a)$, so following the same steps:
$$g'(x)=0 \Leftrightarrow b=\frac{-2x^3+a+3x}{2x}$$

Substituting:

$$\sqrt{((1.5)^2+(\frac{-2x^3+a+3x}{2x})^2}=1 \Leftrightarrow x=\text{Root of }(4z^4-12z^3+6z^2-2az+a^2)$$

And plugging this $x$ into the original function:

$$g(x)=1 \Leftrightarrow b=\text{Length of output exceeds limit of 1000000}$$

Since solving $g(x)=1$ for b depends on $a$, i must get a function $b(a)$, which is where Maple cant process anymore. Does this seem correct or am I missing something? Why can it not process?

Comment: I fail to see how you arrived at your expression for $b$.

Comment: I am unsure I follow what you are doing: should not $a$ = $x$? I any case, for your function $f(x)$, $f(1.5) = -0.25$, while you get $b=2.11$. For that specific value of $a$, would you not want to get $b= 0.75$?

Comment: There must be two values for each, one on either side of the function f(x), i went for the point above f(x), but i am unsure if my final expression is correct. When i isolate g(x)=1 for b i should get a function b(a) since solving for g(x)=1 depends on a

Comment: @iBoughtWinrar, just to make sure I am with you, given your $f(x)$, are you not looking for curves such as $g_1(x) = f(x) + 1$ and $g_2(x)=f(x)-1$?

Comment: I dont think so. I am looking for a function $b(a)$ that can find a $b$-value based on an $a$-value such that the point $(a,b)$ satisfies $g(x)=1$ and $g'(x)=0$. I realise it is confusing, which is why i fail to comprehend.